# thinner border line?

Tags: css

i used:

```
border: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
border-style:solid;
```

but the border line seems to be so thick. i can almost be sure that i have seen thinner border line somewhere. could you make it thinner or did they use images for it?

Comment: +1 I don't know who downvoted your question, but I don't think it was necessary.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that you have the `border` short-hand declaration, which expects several parameters in a precise order. (ie. `border: 1px solid black`)

What you have specified above is invalid. Could that be your problem?

Comment: Downvote was because there's no context or idea what the border is for. Even your answer @jon asks this before assuming the rest. That's why pity upvotes are bad.

Comment: @Crises: This question isn't unintelligible without that context. We clearly know that he's referring to HTML borders and CSS rules. Couple that with the fact that tables have a unique border, it makes my answer very probable.

Comment: @dominic. u were right:) the syntax was wrong and i changed it and now it is only 1px wide:) with the wrong syntax it was like 8-10 px wide=) write an answer and i make it to the correct one=)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

** Copied from my comment on the question itself **

Actually, I just noticed that you have the border short-hand declaration, which expects several parameters in a precise order. (ie. border: 1px solid black) What you have specified above is invalid. Could that be your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
border: 1px 1px 1px 1px
```

try

```
border-width: 1px
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a lighter color was used on the border, (silver instead of black) which often gives the illusion of being thinner.

Answer (score 0):

You may try consolidating your rules into a single short-hand declaration:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

Comment: @noname: Try my second solution then. If it doesn't work, it's likely that something else is messing with the border, which would be discovered through firebug, or an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the borders around the table cells then they will appear thicker because they aren't "collapsable" - you have to write this:

```
 table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

and it should make the borders on every side of a cell one pixel thick (or thin as you want to call it!) within a table.